# Passing member function pointers through templates

Tags: c++, function, c++11, templates

I used this [delegate implementation](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/136799/Lightweight-Generic-C-Callbacks-or-Yet-Another-Del) as a starting point and updated it to use varidadic templates.

I also tried to create a *createCallback*-function which would create a Callback object in one instance, but got a compile error which I do not fully understand.

A very basic compilable example would be this (I removed the *Callback* class for clarity):

```
template<typename R, class T, typename ...P>
class MemberCallbackFactory
{
public:        
    template<R (T::*Func)(P...)>
    inline static void Bind(T* o)
    {
     //
    }
};

template<typename R, class T, typename ...P>
inline void
createCallback(T* obj, R (T::*Func)(P...))
{
    MemberCallbackFactory<R, T, P...>().template Bind<Func>(obj);
}

class Test
{
public:
    void doSomething(int val)
    {
        //
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test t;
    // Works:
    MemberCallbackFactory<void, Test, int>().Bind<&Test::doSomething>(&t);
    // Produces compile error:
    createCallback(&t, &Test::doSomething);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling this example with gcc4.9.2 using C++11 returns:

```
test2.cpp:11:28: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test2.cpp:21:9: error: ‘func’ is not a valid template argument for type ‘void (Test::*)(int)’
        MemberCallbackFactory<R, T, P...>().template Bind<func>(obj);
        ^
test2.cpp:21:9: error: it must be a pointer-to-member of the form ‘&X::Y’
test2.cpp:21:9: error: could not convert template argument ‘func’ to ‘void (Test::*)(int)’
```

So if I pass &Test::doSomething to *createCallback* as the *Func* parameter why can't I forward it to the Bind method? Shouldn't it be of correct type?

If I move the part of the *createCallback* function into *main* it compiles just fine.

Comment: Rather use `std::function` and a lambda expression, than `std::bind` or your own `Bind()` function.

Comment: @user0042: That is an option I am considering. Nevertheless, I would like to understand what is the problem in this case.

Comment: In `createCallback` `Func` is a parameter, i.e. potentially a runtime value. That's why you can't use it as template argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `Func` as a template argument, because it doesn't evaluate to a constant expression. Same problem:

```
template<int> void foo() {}
int A = 5;
foo<A>();
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Now it totally makes sense. 
Shouldn't do that kind of stuff over the holidays :-/